# Getting a date in numbers in java

Tags: java, date

I would like to get the date in numbers in Java.

For example: today is 13th of dec, 2012. I would like to get it in numbers as 13.12.2012

How can I achieve it? Any help would be really appreciated.

P.S I tried something like:

```
Date d = new Date(); 
String date = d.toString().substring(0, 10);
```

But got the output as:`Thu Dec 13`

Comment: did you check [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
```

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Ah. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
Date d = new Date(); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String res = format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to achieve that

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date());
```